# How to handle unknown routes in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am at a complete lost

app.js

```js
app.use('/', userRoutes);
app.use('/adminID', adminRoutes);
app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
next(new AppError(`Url Not Found ${req.originalUrl}`, 404));
}) const ErrorHandler = require('./ErrorHandler.js');
app.use(ErrorHandler);
module.exports = app;
```

[image: question as an image]

Comment: what exactly you want. this is base code. Kindly explain what is your need or what error you are facing.

Comment: Thats what I just spent the last hour trying to do. But the site won't accept my code. I even ran the code through formatters online. The format code button they have didn;t event work unless I submitted something. Then edited it. Even then it still didn't accept my code.   Its late here. And I'm done for the day.

Comment: I did some [edit]ing for you. I recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and reconsidering your attitude. Please add as much textual information from the picture as you like, because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Thank you @Yunnosch. I will reconsider my attitude. However I have been on this site for 6 years. Doesn't seem like much has changed. But my discord buddies can't help me. So I'm here. Thanks for the editing. I appreciate that.

Comment: Please read [ask]: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why it works. But removing `next()` in the function that makes the request. Solves the problem for me.

I was just reading today that, the `next()` doesn't have to be called. Manually, if there is an error it will get called by [default](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html).

```js
exports.create = CatchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.originalUrl)
  const content = await ContentModel(req.body)
  res.send(content)
  await content.save()
    
  // notice how I'm not calling next()
  // before express 5, I believe you had to call next() so the next middleware would run. That is not the case now.
})
```

Happy Coding!